# Filtrar Angular JS por tema

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tengo una web con preguntas que se cargan con *Angular JS*. Estas preguntas tienen título, respuesta y tema al que pertenecen. Quiero incluir una opción para poder navegar entre temas, por un lado haciendo click en anterior y siguiente, y por otro lado pudiendo seleccionar con unos botones a qué tema quieres ir.

Código *HTML*:

```
<div ng-app="preguntas" ng-controller="controles">
    <div id="izquierda" class="controles">
    </div>
    <div id="derecha" class="controles">
    </div>

    <div class="todasPreguntas">
        <input type="search" ng-model="buscar" id="buscar" placeholder="BUSCAR">
        <p ng-model="search.tema" placeholder="TEMA" >1</p>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="x in names | filter : buscar | filter:search:strict" class="pregunta">
                <h2 class="title">{{x.pregunta}}</h2>
                <p> {{x.respuesta}}</p>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Estuve bastante entretenido haciendo esto hasta que lo logre, te dejo un codepen para que lo veas funcionando [Codepen](http://codepen.io/nhernandezt222/pen/bBwjqv)

```
<button ng-click="anterior();" ng-disabled="anterior_disabled" class="title text-center">Anterior</button>
<button ng-click="siguiente();" ng-disabled="siguiente_disabled" class="title text-center">Siguiente</button>
<br>
<br> Seleccione tema
<select ng-model="tema_select" ng-options="tema as tema.nombre_tema for tema in temas track by tema.nombre_tema">
    <option value="" selected>Todos</option>
</select>
<div ng-repeat="x in names | filter: tema_select.nombre_tema ">
    <h2 class="title">{{x.pregunta}}</h2>
    <p> {{x.respuesta}}</p>
</div>
```

Controlador :

```
$scope.names = [{
    pregunta: "¿Pregunta 1?",
    respuesta: "Respuesa 1",
    tema: "tema 1"
}, {
    pregunta: "¿Pregunta 2?",
    respuesta: "Respuesta 2",
    tema: "tema 2"
}, {
    pregunta: "¿Pregunta 3?",
    respuesta: "Respuesta 3",
    tema: "tema 3"
}, ];
$scope.temas = [];
$scope.id = 0;
angular.forEach($scope.names, function(value, key) {
    $scope.temas.push({ nombre_tema: value.tema });
});
$scope.clickButton = function(nombre_tema) {
    $scope.tema_select = { nombre_tema: nombre_tema };
}
$scope.siguiente_disabled = false;
$scope.anterior_disabled = true;
$scope.siguiente = function() {
    $scope.tema_select = { nombre_tema: $scope.temas[$scope.id].nombre_tema };
    $scope.id++;
    if ($scope.id == $scope.temas.length) {
        $scope.siguiente_disabled = true;
        $scope.anterior_disabled = false;
        $scope.id--;
    }
}
$scope.anterior = function() {
    console.log($scope.id);
    $scope.id--;
    $scope.tema_select = { nombre_tema: $scope.temas[$scope.id].nombre_tema };
    if ($scope.id == 0) {
        $scope.anterior_disabled = true;
        $scope.siguiente_disabled = false;
        $scope.id++;
    }
}
```

Para que funcionara lo primero que hice fue hacer un arreglo de preguntas que contienen Pregunta, respuesta y un tema. Luego hice un arreglo `$scope.temas` donde separo del arreglo principal solo los temas.

Creo un `<select>` para ir filtrando por tema con un `ng-repeat` y haciendo opciones.

```
<select ng-model="tema_select" ng-options="tema as tema.nombre_tema for tema in temas track by tema.nombre_tema">
  <option value="" selected>Todos</option>
</select>
```

Luego al `<div>` que repito las publicaciones les agregue el filtro del `ng-model` del selector.

```
<div ng-repeat="x in names | filter: tema_select.nombre_tema ">
  <h2 class="title">{{x.pregunta}}</h2>
  <p> {{x.respuesta}}</p>
</div>
```

Despues trabaje en los botones, como cree un arreglo `temas` cada tema tiene un indice, en este caso `temas[0] = 'tema_1` y asi con los demas en caso que hubieran (yo agregue solo 3). Entonces cree una variable `$scope.id = 0` que sera el indice de este arreglo. Cuando haces click en el boton `Siguiente` este busca en el arreglo `temas` el indice por el valor de `$scope.id` que en primera instancia es 0, por lo tanto trae el primero y luego le suma un valor `$scope.id++` para que cuando hagas nuevamente click en `Siguiente` ya busque el segundo elemento. Si el valor de `$scope.id` es igual a `$scope.temas.lenght`, desactiva el boton siguiente y activa el anterior. La misma funcionalidad tiene el boton `Anterior` pero aqui se resta el valor de `$scope.id` hasta llegar a 0 que es el ultimo item.

Si encuentras algun detalle solo avisa!

Comment: No es lo que buscaba seguro que hay una forma más simple de hacerlo, muchas gracias igualmente.

Comment: Cuando la hagas me comentas!

Answer (score 0):

Usa lo siguiente:

```
ng-repeat=" x in names | filter: { pregunta: buscar || respuesta : buscar }
```